# Jquery step changed variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scroll

Don't know how to names this question correct, so let it be like this.

We have html:

```
<p id="p1"></p>
...
<p id="p14"></p>
```

and jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    for (var i = 70; i <= 980; i = i + 70) {
        if (scroll > i && scroll < i + 70) {
            var c = ???
            $("#p" + c).toggleClass("active");
        }
    }
});
```

what need:
when `$(window).scrollTop()` hits for example value from 70 to 140 class .active adds to #p1

when value from 140 to 210 - class adds to #p2 and removes from #p1 etc.

I know that i can do this with a lot of `if (scroll > 70 && scroll < 140)` costructions, but i want to do it automatically. Just imagine that `<p>` tags are 50 or more.

I think that i need to use addition variable `c` that will be dynamicaly changed from 1 to 14, but don't know how to realize it.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to escape conditional statements.

Comment: Hope that solution exists.
But maybe this function is wrong and  I need to go other way, for example think about scroll position of `<p>` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just:

```
c = Math.floor(scroll / 70)
```

Then c will be a value from 1-14.  The complete code would be:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    for (var i = 70; i <= 980; i = i + 70) {
        if (scroll > i && scroll < i + 70) {
            var c = Math.floor(scroll / 70);
            $("#p" + c).toggleClass("active");
        }
    }
});
```

Now, with that said, you don't really don't need the loop. You could just have:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var c = Math.floor(scroll / 70);
    $("#p" + c).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: So.. yes it works great, but i found that i was wrong with `toggleClass` :)

Changed it to 

     `$("p").removeClass("active");`
     `$("#p" + c).addClass("active");`
and all works fine, so thanks